# How to create Dto using Json C# using Dictionary object or Lists

Tags: json, c#-4.0, dto

am looking to create a Dto class using the following JSON am facing an issue without the hardCode root numbers: "1" and "2" as a JsonPropertyNames it's not working, am using Dictionary object to collect the data, the Dto class: StorageData_v1 has to elemenate hardcode PropertyNam values use dictionary object like was referered/used :

```
**I want to eliminate the below hardcoded values and collect them into Dictionary object like  was used property:  public Dictionary<string, StorageData> Data { get; set; }**

**Note: I have tried using JsonPropertyTagNames =new Object[]{"1",2"} as well, but it didn't work**
 
 /// <summary>
        ///  DBK Data Details
        /// </summary>  
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "2")]
        public DataInfo DataDetails2 { get; set; }

/// <summary>
        ///  DBK Data Details
        /// </summary>  
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "1")]
        public DataInfo DataDetails { get; set; }

JSON string:

{
  "apiVersion": 1,
  "data": {
    "738": {
      "1": {
        "juris": "test",
        "entity": "11",
        "storage": {
          "$podDbkRawBase64": "test"
        },
        "instance": "1",
        "calcJobId": "13d1c32252f24795",
        "formIndex": "10",
        "ReturnId": "b93c4acaa0c0"
      }
    },
    "463": {
      "1": {
        "juris": "test",
        "entity": "test",
        "storage": {
          "$podRawBase64": "test2"
        },
        "instance": "1",
        "calcJobId": "13d1c32252f",
        "formIndex": "4",
        "ReturnId": "b93c4aca"
      }
    }
  }
}


**Dto class:**
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;

namespace TestModels.Dto
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Unit data object
    /// </summary>
    public class StorageData_v1
    {
        /// <summary>
        ///  Input Screen Unit
        /// </summary>
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "apiVersion")]
        public string ApiVersion { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        ///  Input Screen fields
        /// </summary>
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "data")]
        public Dictionary<string, StorageData> Data { get; set; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// DBK storage Information for DTO
    /// </summary>
    public class StorageData
    {
        /// <summary>
        ///  DBK Data Details
        /// </summary>  
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "1")]
        public DataInfo DataDetails { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        ///  DBK Data Details
        /// </summary>  
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "2")]
        public DataInfo DataDetails2 { get; set; }

     }

    public class DataInfo
    {
        /// <summary>
        ///  Jurisditction
        /// </summary>
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "juris")]
        public string Jurisdiction { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        ///  DBK Entity type
        /// </summary>
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "entity")]
        public string Entity { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// DBK data Instance
        /// </summary>
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "instance")]
        public string Instance { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// DBK data Calc JobId
        /// </summary>
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "calcJobId")]
        public string CalcJobId { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// DBK data Index
        /// </summary>
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "formIndex")]
        public string FormIndex { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Return Id
        /// </summary>
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "ReturnId")]
        public string ReturnId { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        ///  Data fields
        /// </summary>
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "storage")]
        public Storage Storage { get; set; }
    }

    public class Storage
    {
        /// <summary>
        ///  Base 64 data
        /// </summary>
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "$podRawBase64")]
        public string PodRawBase64 { get; set; }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
public class Storage
{
    [JsonProperty("$podDbkRawBase64")]
    public string PodDbkRawBase64 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("$podRawBase64")]
    public string PodRawBase64 { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public int apiVersion { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "data")]
    public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, DataItem>> DataItems { get; set; }
}

public class DataItem
{
    public string juris { get; set; }
    public string entity { get; set; }
    public string instance { get; set; }
    public string calcJobId { get; set; }
    public string fromIndex { get; set; }
    public string ReturnId { get; set; }
    public Storage storage { get; set; }
}
```

And you can deserialize you object like this:

```
Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(myJsonResponse);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I don't want to use the hardcoded class names public class _738
{
    public _1 _1 { get; set; }
}

public class _463
{
    public _1 _1 { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    public _738 _738 { get; set; }
    public _463 _463 { get; set; }
}

Help me transform into Dictionary objects or any generic collections without hard code values

Comment: @MohanK I have updated my answer. Is that what you need?

Comment: Thank you @Sean Stayns..It's working, I have tried nested this statement before as well: public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, DataItem>> DataItems { get; set; } .. Only the issue is instead of JsonConvert.Deserialize method has tested with ToObjsonReturnData.ToObject<DBKStorageData_v1>(); .. Some how ToObject not triggering well.. Thank you once again

Comment: @MohanK You are welcome. Can you mark the answer as solution? You can do it with clicking of the check arrow and clicking on the arrow up. Have a nice day.

Comment: @Sen ..Have more question, In the same Json file  have one more parameter data like as follows under "Storage" node have storage": {
          "$unnamedDbkFields": [
            1,
            "T",
             1,
          
            350000,
    "\\u0000",                   
         ]

  ...  Have created    
        public UnNamedDBKField[] UnNamedDBKField { get; set; }
    }

    public class UnNamedDBKField
    {
        public dynamic UnNameFields { get; set; }
    }

but  Not working, might we need a Custom JsonConvert class here?